# Can I sort a list of dictionaries by the result of a substraction of two of it's values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is coming from a database which has the following values:

```
storageRoom = 'id', 'max_stock', 'min_stock', 'temperature', 'humidity'
```

My question is, how can I sort it by the result of 'max_stock' - 'min_stock'. It isn't possible to add a new key on the dictionary as I get it from a database which does not have this value.

Comment: It _is_ always possible to add new keys to a dictionary. They are mutable objects.

Comment: If my answer helped, would you mind upvoting? It contributes to the community :)

Comment: @alec935 I don't have enough reputation to do it. Thanks

Comment: You do now :) (>15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a sorted list from a dictionary `storageRoom`, you can do:

```
list = sorted(storageRoom.items(), key=lambda k: k['max_stock']-k['min_stock'])
```

Quick note: Wherever you're getting your dictionary from, you can add to it as much as you want. Dictionaries are mutable.